# PrecomputedText has a getWidth() method but PrecomputedTextCompat does not?

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat

I'm trying to take advantage of the new-ish [`PrecomputedTextCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/PrecomputedTextCompat) class but it appears that it is missing a method that the framework's version of the class ([`PrecomputedText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/PrecomputedText)) has: [`getWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/PrecomputedText#getWidth(int,%20int)). Unfortunately, the framework version of the class was added in [API 28](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) so I can't use it, that's way above our minimum SDK level at the moment.

I definitely need this method for what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know of a suitable replacement? The returned value doesn't necessarily have to be a `float`, could be just an `int` (pixels).

Places I've looked for a replacement, but haven't found an answer:

- [`AppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView)
- [`MaterialTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textview/MaterialTextView)
- [`PrecomputedTextCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/PrecomputedTextCompat)
- [`PrecomputedTextCompat.Params`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/PrecomputedTextCompat.Params)
- [`TextViewCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/TextViewCompat)

Thank you!!

Comment: I've since made a post about this missing API on the official issue tracker. Please ⭐️ if you need this feature too. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154300817 thank you!!